# Spring boot logger info what is Hypersql

Tags: java, spring-boot, info

I've been developing my app using spring-boot with thymeleaf  and today I've noticed a new log info what is it?

```
2022-06-14 10:20:48.223  INFO 2692 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] hsqldb.db.HSQLDB6BD103EBD8.ENGINE        : dataFileCache open start
```

I found out it has relation to hypersql ? Is that correct ? Is it normal ?

Answer (score 0):

This is `INFO` level logger for `hsqldb` which is clearly showing some process has been started. This can be because you might have enabled `root` level logging for all components.

If you want to disable any such `INFO` level loggers for `hsqldb`  then you can modify your property file  such that:

```
logging.level.org.hsqldb.hsqldb=ERROR //only error loggers will be shown on logger
```

Or

```
logging.level.org.hsqldb.hsqldb=OFF  // no logger related to hsqldb will be shown
```